# How to get Int value with List<Int> of Realm in Swift?

Tags: swift, list, realm

````
```swift
// define a class
class Model: Object {
    var listNumber = List<Int>()
}

// initialize the listNumber
for i in 0..<10 {
    model.listNumber.append(0)
}
```
````

- so, how to get the value of the listNumber?
- I can't find a way to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can access Realm List elements just like elements of an array

```
func printList() {
    for value in listNumber {
        print(value)
    }
}

func printListElement() {
    print(listNumber[4])
}
```